# Output first match for each pattern

Tags: grep

Text file to be searched (input.txt):

```
GREEN TREE CONIFER
GREEN BUSH BERRY
RED LEAF MAPLE
RED TRUNK MAPLE
```

Input pattern file; one word per line (patterns.txt):

```
GREEN
MAPLE
```

Desired output:

```
GREEN TREE CONIFER
RED LEAF MAPLE
```

My command:

```
$ grep -m1 -f patterns.txt input.txt
```

However, this only returns:

```
GREEN TREE CONIFER
```

How should I modify my command to get only the first match, from each pattern in the patterns.txt file?

Comment: I think awk is a better tool for this task.

Comment: After a quick check of the GNU [`grep` manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html), I don't think it can be done with a single invocation of `grep`.  A `while` loop reading lines from `patterns.txt` and then invoking `grep -m1 -e "$pattern" "$file"` would do the job relatively sanely.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't come up with a single grep invokation solution.

Here I propose a loop to get first occurence for each pattern in input file.

```
p=$(cat pattern.txt)
for x in $(seq $(echo "$p" | wc -l)); do
 cat input.txt | grep -m 1 "$(echo "$p" | head -n $x | tail -n 1)"
done
```